# How to run sicpy.signal freqz in C# / ASP.NET Core?

Tags: python, c#, numpy, asp.net-core, scipy

I need to run Python source code (.py) with dependencies on `numpy` and `scipy.signal` in the ASP.NET Core context. I've found IronPython to be a suitable solution, but it doesn't support these two dependencies ([GitHub issue #355](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/issues/355)).

So, I decided to automatically generate C# code from the Python one and manually check all build errors. All looks promising, `numpy` seems to be supported by [Numpy.NET](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET), but my missing puzzle is the [`freqz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html) method of `scipy.signal`.

Example of usage:

`w, h = signal.freqz(b, a, worN=freq_hz, fs=fs_hz)`

Questions on the `freqz` function:

1. Is there any C# fork of the function?
2. Is there any source code of the function, so I can generate C# code from it?
3. I was wondering if I can use MATLAB [`freqz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) function. Are these two functions equivalent? Is it possible to run that MATLAB function in the C# context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, solution was to rewrite `freqz` function (I didn't need to rewrite `freqz` completely, just part of the logic though) to C# along its dependent code (using Numpy):

```cs
public static (NDarray w, NDarray h) freqz(NDarray b,
                                           NDarray a,
                                           NDarray? worN,
                                           float fs = (float)Math.PI * 2)
{
    using var b_ = np.atleast_1d(b);
    using var a_ = np.atleast_1d(a);

    NDarray w = np.atleast_1d(worN);

    w = 2 * np.pi * w / fs;

    using var i = np.array(new Complex[] { new(real: 0, imaginary: -1) });
    var zm1 = (i * w).exp();

    var nppPolyval_b = npp_polyval(zm1, b_);
    var nppPolyval_a = npp_polyval(zm1, a_);
    NDarray h = nppPolyval_b / nppPolyval_a;

    w = w * fs / (2 * np.pi);

    return (w, h);
}

private static NDarray npp_polyval(NDarray x, NDarray c)
{
    using var c_ = np.array(c, ndmin: 1, copy: false);

    var c0 = c_[":, -1"] + x * 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= c_.size; i++)
    {
        c0 = c_[$":, -{i}"] + (c0 * x);
    }
    return c0;
}
```